# Why is a space counted as a syntax error?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am using Python 3.1 IDLE and have found that the space (which I will mark out as such - _) is being highlighted by IDLE as a syntax error.  I would like to know if anyone knows what the problem is and offer a solution.  I know it looks wrong, but the underscore is just there to highlight where IDLE says the problem is.  I can't work out what the issue with that line and the next line is.

```
    def attrSelection():
        while attrChoice!=6
            if attrChoice==1:
                attrChoice=Power
                baseAttr=int(basePow)
                attrEditor()
     _      elif attrChoice==2:
                attrChoice=Health
                baseAttr=int(baseHlth)
                attrEditor()
            elif attrChoice==3
                attrChoice=Wisdom
                baseAttr=int(baseWis)
                attrEditor()
            elif attrChoice==4:
                attrChoice=Dexterity
                baseAttr=int(baseDex)
                attrEditor()
            elif attrChoice==5:
                assignRandom()
            else:
                print('Option does not exist.  Please enter option in range 1-6.')
                attrChoice=input('Choice: ')
```

Comment: Are you using tabs for indentation? If so, that’s your answer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: The IDE highlights it; that's not a traceback. Yet.

Answer (score 5):

The IDE may points you to the errors here:

```
def attrSelection():
    while attrChoice!=6
    ...
        elif attrChoice==3
    ...
```

You are missing `:` after the `6` and `3`. Otherwise, everything looks fine, assuming you didn't also missed the indentation at the beginning as you are listing the code.

Comment: if that's indeed the reason for IDLE to show that error, then IDLE really sucks :-s

Answer (score 0):

python is really picky about spaces, because it uses spaces for defining code blocks. That's a design choice, it's radical, and has its proponent and opponent. But as a consequence, you need to be really careful in how many spaces you put in front of a line of code, because python will not understand something like:

```
i = 1
 j = 2
  k = 3
```

as logically, it would mean that `i`, `j` and `k` are not in the same blocks, which is impossible as a block shall begin with special statements, usually ending with a colon (`:`). So python will just throw the same syntax error you've seen in your code saying that there's a problem with spaces!

In your case, it's likely you're using tabs for alignment, which makes two characters to get something aligned at column 8. But somewhere in your code, you had spaces instead of tabs, making it 5 characters to have your code aligned at column 8

```
<TAB><TAB>i = 1
<TAB>     j = 2
```

so if you consider tabs as spaces, here's what gets written:

```
  i = 1
     j = 2
```

thus python not understanding your code! As a general advice, only use spaces never tabs to indent your code, so you can't be tricked by tab/spaces mess up.

N.B.: as the others are telling, your code is indeed being wrong, missing colons at the end of the following statements:

```
    while attrChoice!=6
        ...
        elif attrChoice==3
        ...
```

as they pointed that out, I did not place it in my answer until now. Though if your IDE is giving you an error in the indentation, whereas it's a missing colon, then you should consider changing IDE, as your IDE is really failing at giving relevant errors/warnings that can help code faster and more easily.

Comment: True, but not really relevant to the OP, who simply forgot the required colon in the `while` statement.

Comment: then the IDE really sux at finding errors and giving relevant error messages! :-)

Answer (score -1):

There are colons missing after the while and second elif. It scanned fine in idle for me after adding those.

Comment: Just curious why I got dinged for this? It's essentially the same answer as BSH who posted as I was typing. Is it because I didn't include a code snippet?

Comment: I've tried scanning in IDLE after putting the colons in.  The highlighted space was just moved one space along.  I have no idea why that is.

Comment: I do not feel you should have been dinged down.  However, having joined just to post this question, I don't have the reputation to knock you back up.

Comment: @user3616997 - I'm at work, so I had to use 2.7.x rather than 3.x. I don't know if they handle what's wrong differently. I tried again using a different method to copy and paste from your post and results still ok. I wonder if there's a hidden character in the original that doesn't copy/paste as expected. When you tried with the colons added, did you use your original, or copy from the post in StEx? You could try cutting/deleting the bad line and retyping it (or the entire code block.)

Comment: I have tried retyping the entire block from scratch (making sure I added the colons.  I have altered my code slightly to see if I could eradicate the issue.  I removed the 'while' loop from the system because it would normally never leave the loop.  I am wondering if you could recommend a decent freeware Python IDE.  I am trying PyScripter, but that doesn't seem to work properly.